# Анимация по таймеру

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, css-animation

Подключил animate.css, хочу чтобы работала анимация. Пишу код в самом конце html:

```
</body>
<script>
    var scaleElem = document.getElementById('par_mak');
    setInterval(myMethod_one, 3000);
    function myMethod_one( )
    {
        scaleElem.classList.add('animated');
        setTimeout(function(){ scaleElem.classList.remove('animated infinite bounce'); }, 300);
    }
</script>
```

Получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить и получить анимацию по таймеру, когда загрузиться страница?

Comment: Перенесите ваш код в событие `onload`. У вас не успевает загрузиться страница, возможно.

Comment: не, перенесите `var scaleElem = document.getElementById('par_mak');` в `myMethod_one`

Comment: не работает господа - также Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: еще меня смущает в редакторе серым выделен         setInterval(myMethod_one, 3000);

Comment: пора показать html с `id="par_mak"`. Ясно, что на странице такого нет.

Comment: @Igor вы совершенно правы, был класс `"par_mak"` изменил класс на id и все заработало. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс "par_mak" изменил класс на id и все заработало